# Getting the value of an inner list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following simple data structure. A list of students, each with a unique ID. Each student has a list of courses they are enrolled in. Courses also have unique IDs, but will be members of multiple studentCourses lists (as each course is enrolled in by multiple students).

I'm trying to find a particular grade value, by studentId and courseId. I'm using the linq query below. I'm still a little shakey with my linq, and was wondering if the query i've written is correct? It does work correctly, but could it be changed to be more elegant/readable?

```
class Student {
    int studentId;
    string studentName;
    List<Course> studentCourses;
}

class Course {
    int courseId;
    string courseName;
    int grade;
}

List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
//populate list.                
int studentGrade = students
    .Where(c => c.studentId == 1)
    .Select(c => c.studentCourses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.courseId == 1).grade)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Just another way. `int studentGrade = students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.studentId == 1).studentCourses.FirstOrDefault(c => c.courseId==1).grade;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int studentGrade = students
                      .Where(d=>d.studentId == 1)
                      .FirstOrDefault().studentCourses
                      .FirstOrDefault(d=>d.courseId == 1).grade;
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a bit of query syntax:

```
var studentGrade = 
    (from student in students
    where student.studentId == 1
    from course in student.studentCourses
    where course.courseId == 1
    select course.grade)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

If any part (student / course) of the lookup fails, the sequence will be empty and `FirstOrDefault` will give you a zero.

This could also be done with `SelectMany`, which is what these multiple `from`s translate into.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the student and course exists then

```
int studentGrade = students
                      .FirstOrDefault(s => s.studentId == 1).studentCourses
                      .FirstOrDefault(c => c.courseId == 1).grade;
```

else something like

```
var student = students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.studentId == 1);
var course = student != null ? student.studentCourses.FirstOrDefault(c => c.courseId == 1) : null;
int studentGrade = course != null ? course.grade : -1;
```